# Cisco GRE Tunnel on 6504E

Tags: cisco

i have cisco 6504e with WS-X6704-10GE and VS-S2T-10G-XL and i want to lunch 10-12x GRE tunnel with all of GRE tunnels has around 500-600mbps traffic, i want to know 6504e can handle this GRE traffic ? it does not affect on the CPU ?
Thank yo.u

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to my interpretation of the [specifications](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/catalyst-6500-series-supervisor-engine-2t/data_sheet_c78-648214.html), the answer is Yes, assuming a normal mix of packet sizes.